# Python selenium can't find class properly

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I use selenium for get some specific information from webpages. Although normally it works, selenium have begun to doesn't work properly. Or I can't understand. The HTML code that I want to get information is this part:

```
<div class="uiBoxContainer classifiedDescription" id="classifiedProperties">    
<ul>
    <li class="selected">ADSL</li>
     <li class="">Ahşap Doğrama</li>
     <li class="">Akıllı Ev</li>
     <li class="selected">Alarm (Hırsız)</li>
     <li class="">Alarm (Yangın)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get "selected" classes' text. And I write that code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")


url = "https://www.sahibinden.com/ilan/822660990/detay"
browser.get(url)
alltaki_ozellikler = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.selected")
for i in alltaki_ozellikler:    
    print(i.text)
browser.close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdQ4S.png)
The code works fine when I want to get some other class. But when I want to get "selected" class with this code, it prints some empty classes in this HTML list and some "selected" classes. But I want to get only "selected" classes. I am new at Python and Selenium. I will appreciate if you help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'selected')]") Try that one instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But it gave the same result again.

Comment: Oh, it worked. I try to change the page that I want to get the information. I think there are lots of ads on the previous page. So the code didn't work. But I try the code in a simple page and it worked. Thank you very much again.

Comment: np have a nice day